# Pandas Python Moving Rows

Tags: pandas

I am new to Pandas and I have a csv file that I want to move every row 2 & 3 to value1 and value2 column. Could someone please help me out? I can't seem to figure it out.

```
data, value1,   value2

1.00        
2.00        
3.00        
4.00        
5.00        
6.00        
7.00        
8.00        
9.00
```

output would turn into this

```
one,    value1, value2

1.00    2.00    3.00        
4.00    5.00    6.00        
7.00    8.00    9.00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More general solution is create [`MultiIndex.from_arrays`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html) with modulo and floor division of [`numpy.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
print (df)
   data
0   1.0
1   2.0
2   3.0
3   4.0
4   5.0
5   6.0
6   7.0
7   8.0
8   9.0
9  10.0

a =  np.arange(len(df.index)) 
print (a)
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]

df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([a % 3, a // 3])
print (df)
     data
0 0   1.0
1 0   2.0
2 0   3.0
0 1   4.0
1 1   5.0
2 1   6.0
0 2   7.0
1 2   8.0
2 2   9.0
0 3  10.0
```

---

```
df1 = df['data'].unstack(0)
df1.columns=['data','value1','value2']
print (df1)
   data  value1  value2
0   1.0     2.0     3.0
1   4.0     5.0     6.0
2   7.0     8.0     9.0
3  10.0     NaN     NaN
```

Comment: Wow. This is great! Much appreciate it! I have so much reading to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a numpy method `reshape` then convert back to dataframe with `pd.DataFrame` and name your columns.

```
pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(3,3), columns=['data','value1','value2'])
```

Output:

```
   data  value1  value2
0     1       2       3
1     4       5       6
2     7       8       9
```

Comment: Getting value error:
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-268-eefe18ff0f4e> in <module>()
----> 1 na = pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape(3,3), columns=['data','value1','value2'])

ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged

Comment: This solution is limited to 9 values.  jezrael's solution is more robust.